# "Das ist nicht fair"

Tags: loanword, english

I was browsing the comments in a recent discussion and was struck by the use of English expressions by native German correspondents. One asked (in German) why his answer got a "downvote", and the other responded "it wasn't me" before continuing in German. To which the first replied (in German) concluding with the phrase "das ist nicht fair".

"Downvote" is a fairly obvious adaptation. I remember another discussion on the verb "like" in the context of its Facebook usage: whether the past participle should be "geliked" or "geliken". But I'm interested in people's opinions about the other two expressions in this little exchange: "it wasn't me", and "das is nicht fair".

I hardly consider it a weakness of the German language that it can incorporate these kinds of expressions: quite the contrary. But I wonder how native speakers hear usages of this sort, and whether there are perhaps equally good "German" words which could convey the same nuance.

Although I am putting the question in English, I enjoy reading responses in either language.

Comment: Das Wort "fair" ist für meine Begriffe zu 100% integriert. Ich kannte das Wort lange, bevor mir überhaupt bewusst wurde, dass es aus einer anderen Sprache stammt. Es ist so integriert, dass Kinder, die schreiben lernen, es teilweise nicht als fremd erkennen und als "fähr" o.ä. schreiben wollen.^^

Comment: Zur Zeit ist die Frage sehr meinungslastig und außerdem werden zwei Fragen auf einmal gestellt. Ich denke aber, dass Fragen nach deutschen Entsprechungen von *fair* und *it wasn’t me* und danach, wie gut diese treffen, gute Fragen wären.

Comment: The "das ist nicht fair" was referring to the fact that there were 2 downvotes now. It had nothing to do with the "it wasn't me" (it was my comment, so I know)

Comment: The discussion was slightly different than what you quoted here. However, "fair" is fairly integrated in German and "It wasn't me" is just a phrase. I don't think that it's exceptional to put a phrase into a different language.

Comment: It's a bilingual site so it's expected that most members understand both languages and in this context mixing languages or code-switching is not unusual, even within a single sentence. i agree about fair, I lived in Germany as a child long before the internet and long before Germans commonly spoke english, and i was confused for a moment there, since I now recognise it as unquestionably english, but it also seemed to be familiar usage in german (confusing because I often doubt my memories).

Answer (score 10):

Ich hab im IDS-Korpus (Cosmas II) eine kurze Recherche gemacht mit einer schnellen Auswertung; für eine wissenschaftlichere Auswertung habe ich momentan leider keine Zeit.

Zwei Tendenzen sind aber recht eindeutig, was die Phrase »Das ist nicht fair« betrifft:

1. Im Verhältnis zu ihrem Gegenteil »Das ist fair« wird sie wesentlich frequenter verwendet (ca. 3:1).
2. Obwohl in relativ vielen Textsorten Fundstellen vorhanden sind, wird sie v. a. in Plenarprotokollen verwendet, was auf eine häufigere Verwendung in der gesprochenen Sprache hindeutet.

Die Kookurrenzanalyse ist statistisch unspezifisch geblieben, es lässt sich auf Datenbasis des Cosmas also kein spezifischer semantischer Kontext feststellen, in dem die Phrase vorwiegend verwendet wird, wenngleich ich rein gefühlsmäßig meinen Vorrednern beipflichten würde, dass sich gerade Wettkämpfe/Sport als Kontext anbieten – nur fehlt dafür eben der empirische Beweis.

Als Äquivalent würde ich v. a. folgende Phrase sehen:

> Das ist nicht gerecht. / Das ist ungerecht.

(Die Ergebnisse sind ähnlich denen für »Das ist nicht fair«, wenngleich ca. doppelt so oft verwendet, Verhältnis 4:1)

Für das Adjektiv *fair* isoliert betrachtet bietet der Duden-Eintrag einen guten ersten Überblick.

Wie ebenfalls schon erwähnt, würde ich »It wasn’t me« auch als intertextuelle Anspielung ansehen, ohne Subtext/Anspielung/Referenz sind ganze englische Sätze in einem Posting eher selten, denke ich.

Comment: Danke an @Wrzlprmft für die Korrekturen, »Substantiv fair« war in der Tat ein peinlicher Fehler... Die »Konkurrenzanalyse« habe ich wieder auf »Kookurrenzanalyse« zurückgeändert, dieser Begriff bezeichnet ein [korpusanalytisches Verfahren](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/ka.html).

Answer (score 5):

Duden lists a few alternatives (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fair).

But first, we should think about context. We're not talking about a game here with set rules, but of social interaction, in which a certain behaviour does not violate set rules, but rules seen as common, at least by one party.
Given that, I see three fitting words:

> gerecht
>   anständig
>   korrekt

"gerecht" means "just", I find the connotation to justice too strong. You basically say that someone acts "ungerecht".
"anständig" is better, but I think it is more fitting for rules which are widely accepted. To take the last cookie is "nicht anständig".
"korrekt" fits best, I think. "sich korrekt verhalten" means to be fair, to do the right thing.

However, fair is deeply rooted in the German language. Actually, when I read your post, at first I didn't realize what it was about...

**Interesting:** Duden lists an Old High German root for fair, "fagar"! So if someone knows how to shift it to New High German, we can have our own, native word ;-))

Comment: Im Fußball-Bereich sagt man nur "Es war ein faires Spiel". Kein Mensch würde die von Duden angegebenen deutschen Varianten benützen. Und dieses "fair" ist meiner Meinung nach schon mindestens 60 Jahre im deutschen Sprachgebrauch.

Comment: Deshalb bin ich ja auf den Kontext eingegangen. "Anständiges Spiel" finde ich aber auch nicht ungebräuchlich.

Comment: At Veredomon - Ja, durchaus brauchbar, aber wer sagt das ? Höchstens Papa, wenn Söhnchen fragt, Papa was heißt "faires Spiel". Dann kann er mit "anständiges Spiel"übersetzen, aber wahrscheinlich gebraucht er einen  weiteren Anglizismus und sagt: Es wurde nicht gefoult.

Answer (score 3):

Using English words can be really popular among some people. Unfortunately, in some cases it can be exaggerated, especially in the form of 'Denglish' and if coming from the ones who try to come over as young and hip without necessarily being so, ie. managers and big corporations (Deutsche Bahn is a prime example). You might enjoy this article: http://www.thelocal.de/20140107/denglisch-ist-for-losers-german

Though German, I didn't grow up in Germany, and when I moved there to finish high school I did get some strange reactions for accidentally using the wrong words, or even just a different accent. So that said, I'm probably not the kind of native speaker you're looking for. If trying to use 'pure' German, I'd say "das ist nicht gerecht" (though fair sounds less harsh in my ears); "it wasn't me" is a pop reference (isn't it a song from a few years back?), so translating it to "ich war's nicht!" would loose half the message. "Liken" is actually a nice example, as "mögen" doesn't capture the facebook-meaning of the word - I don't think there is a good translation for that term (is there a German version of Facebook so anyone could check?).

Comment: "It wasn't me" ist in der Tat ein Song, aber an den habe ich nicht gedacht, als ich ich den Kommentar verfasst hatte. Zumindest nicht bewusst. (Also den Kommentar, der mit Ausschlag für die Frage hier war.)

Comment: FYI: The German version of Facebook uses "Gefällt mir" rather than the nevertheless popular "liken".

Comment: Aber „ich habe den Beitrag als mir gefallend gekennzeichnet“ ist doch irgendwie umständlicher als „ich habe den Beitrag geliked“.

Comment: @Em1 hmm.. vielleicht ist "it wasn't me" schon so mainstream geworden, dass es sich vom Lied abgekoppelt hat? "ich war's nicht" hat für mich auch den Beiklang von etwas, was ein 8-jähriger rufen würde, Lied hin oder her, ich hätte wahrscheinlich auch "it wasn't me" geschrieben...

Answer (score 1):

"Das ist nicht fair" ist sicher in Ordnung für alle Deutschsprechenden; "fair" wird zum Beispiel im Zusammenhang mit Sport sehr häufig benutzt. So etwas wie "geliked" hört man in der Umgangssprache, aber bei mir erzeugt es ein schlechtes Gefühl im Magen.

Answer (score 1):

@Marty: Das ist unfair! Das ist ungerecht! I think most negations are done by prefixing "un-" instead of using "nicht". At least when you use it as a normal statement.

If you read somewhere "Das ist nicht fair!", it is like putting emphasis on the last two words and saying them slower to make sure the other person understands it is really not fair.

The word "fair" itself is a perfectly normal german word you learn in Kindergarden, mostly in the context of someone or something being "unfair". :)

People over let's say 60 might use "ungerecht" instead of "unfair", but even they would understand it.

Comment: Der erste Teil Deiner Antwort ist eher ein Kommentar zur eigentlichen Frage nwelchen Du noch nicht geben kannst).

Answer (score 1):

Im Google Ngram Viewer taucht das Wort "fair" zuerst 1732 auf, "unfair" sogar 1727 und "Fairness" 1862.  Alle drei sind seit dem späten 19. Jahrhundert in stets zunehmendem Gebrauch. Nach fast 300 Jahren Gebrauch empfindet kein Deutscher das Wort "fair" und seine Ableitungen mehr als fremd.

Comment: Ich habe da auch mal geschaut, aber man muss vorsichtig sein. Die Fundstellen können durchaus Shakespeare-Zitate und OCR-Fehler sein.

Answer (score 1):

My guessings to this:

Downvote, only one of many words we picked and integrated in our language.
But i think it is more common in the internet.

It wasn't me = Reference to "Shaggy = It wasn't me"

geliked = gefällt
geliken = never heard of this, but i guess you just mean "liken"

As you spoke from adaptations, i read more of the answers of other users,.. i felt over Kindergarten. :P

> Little Ms Whoops asked:
>
> (is there a German version of Facebook so anyone could check?)

Hey, there. Sure there is, we are allowed to used it. (not as harsh as it maybe sounds)
I do not use facebook anymore, but as i remeber the german "Like"-button is called "Gefällt mir" ("I like"), correctly i should say "Das gefällt mir" ("I like this/that")
or even better "Ich möchte zum Ausdruck bringen, dass ich Gefallen daran gefunden habe." ("I would like to say, that i like this/that")

Ok, please do not throw stones at me! I know this buttons would become a little bit.. uhm,. big?!

Hopefully i did not violate any rules. This is my very first post here. I will now or a bit later go and search for some rules. :)

Have a nice Day!

Comment: Wie bereits bei einer anderen Antwort angemerkt, "It wasn't me" ist in der Tat ein Song, aber an den habe ich nicht gedacht, als ich ich den Kommentar verfasst hatte. Zumindest nicht bewusst. (Also den Kommentar, der mit Ausschlag für die Frage hier war.)

Answer (score 0):

This question is highly dependent on personal opinions. For me, I think most of the English words used in German are unnecessary. The are some words that are a good extension to the German language, like *fit* (healthy) or *stress*. Other words are just waste of our language. You don't really need to use the English words, but it's trendy to use them. I personally hope that this trend abates at some point. We have a word for like (*gefallen*), also a word for downvote (*abwerten*).

It is true, that English has finer nuances than German, but mostly there is no need for that. Some people argument that the high usage of English words is because we don't have a word for it. My argument is why don't invent a new word? Why was there no problems for hundreds of years to invent new words and now we aren't able for that anymore? Also some existing words get replaced, which is kinda stupid.

To my ears, many English words in the German language sound terrible. *Fair* is okay because we can pronounce it in German. A good reason not to use *gerecht* isn't existing if you ask me.